# Centering button in bootstrap column. Overlaps when screen minimized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have centered my button in one of my bootstap columns. Everything works fine until I get to a smaller screen size and my button overlaps my other column that has text in it. When I play around with the margin things get even weirder. 
[image: This is when it's desktop size]
[image: This what my problem looks like]

```css
.center-btn-container {
  position: relative;
}

.paragraph-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 214px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #F36819, #F7931D);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <span class="col-1-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra.</span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 center-btn-container">
  <button type="button" class="btn paragraph-btn">Button</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does the class col-1-paragraph do? if you change the <span> (element is in-line) to <p> (element is block-line), it should stop the overlapping issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the right column colapses and has no height because it's children (the button) is absolutely positioned and doesn't take any space + the translate -50% which brings the button up 50% of the height of the buton inside of a container of 1px height (default from bootstrap).

Simply give that column a min-height of 40px (the height of the button) and it should look ok. (I've added ".col-md-6" to the selector so it will override the bootstrap min-height of 1px)

```css
.center-btn-container {
  position: relative;
}
.col-md-6.center-btn-container {
    min-height: 40px;
}
.paragraph-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 214px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #F36819, #F7931D);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <span class="col-1-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra.</span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 center-btn-container">
  <button type="button" class="btn paragraph-btn">Button</button>
</div>
</div>
```